# How do you jquery # tags and set div id's dynamically in list view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listview, html-injections

Hello Everyone i wanted to dynamically set both the jquery id and listview div id dynamically 
I have  looked across the internet with out any good examples.

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
    // I need to set the #accLstViewInner to #accLstViewInner + itemID
            $("#accLstViewInner").accordion({
                collapsible: true, active: false
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and set

```
     <asp:ListView ID="lstAccordionViewInner" Runat="server" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            // set the div below to #accLstViewInner + itemID as well
            <div id="accLstViewInner">
```

Any Good links to resources or ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why not instead just not use id's?

Comment: @KevinB, cause user2817020 wants to generate code like accLstViewInner_1, accLstViewInner_2, accLstViewInner_3

Comment: @EricHerlitz Obviously, but there's very little reason to do so. if you need it to be enumerated, it already is even without the id's, each one has an index in the DOM. Otherwise you end up with crap like `$('#accLstViewInner_1, #accLstViewInner_2, #accLstViewInner_3, #accLstViewInner_4, #accLstViewInner_5')` or `$("[id^=accLstViewInner]")` instead of `$(".accLstViewInner")`

Comment: @KevinB, in general I agree but there are cases when you want more control than class selection

Comment: @Kevin  I did get it to work with class nested but as kevin said for nested listviews i am coming into scenarios that will justify the added control so that i am confident that the id are all unique and adjustable encase of any odd css dependencies that can happen between back and from end development with different modules , etc and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as dynamically in the code you mention. The common practice would be to have two listviews (or repeaters) to generate the code or to output the result from your object directly in your selector or a js-variable.

I assume you feed if from code-behind with something like

```
lstAccordionViewInner.DataSource = someListObject;
lstAccordionViewInner.DataBind();
```

As an example

```
class someList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// and an example instance, should be put in a property if you want to access it from your aspx-code
var someListObject = new List<someList>()
{
    new someList() {Id = 1, Name = "#accLstViewInner"},
    new someList() {Id = 2, Name = "#accLstViewInner"},
    new someList() {Id = 3, Name = "#accLstViewInner"},
    new someList() {Id = 4, Name = "#accLstViewInner"},
    new someList() {Id = 5, Name = "#accLstViewInner"}
};

string jqueryResult = someListObject.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, item) => current + string.Concat(item.Name, "_", item.Id, item == someListObject.Last() ? string.Empty : ", "));
// #accLstViewInner_1, #accLstViewInner_2, #accLstViewInner_3, #accLstViewInner_4, #accLstViewInner_5
```

This result you could use directly in your jQuery selector

```
$('<%=someListObject.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, item) => current + string.Concat(item.Name, "_", item.Id, item == someListObject.Last() ? string.Empty : ", "));%>').accordion({
    collapsible: true, active: false
});
```

When the page is rendered this would become

```
$('#accLstViewInner_1, #accLstViewInner_2, #accLstViewInner_3, #accLstViewInner_4, #accLstViewInner_5').accordion({
    collapsible: true, active: false
});
```

But, since you have this pattern I'd say it's stupid to do that much work only to build a selector unless you want extreme control. Use wildcards instead

```
$("[id^=accLstViewInner]").accordion({
    collapsible: true, active: false
});
```

To handle the listview...

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lstAccordionViewInner" Runat="server" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        // set the div below to #accLstViewInner + itemID as well
        <div id='accLstViewInner_<%#Eval("Id") %>' />'>
        // or possibly
        <div id='accLstViewInner_<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>' />'>
        // ...
        <div id='accLstViewInner_<% DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem("Id"))%>' />'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will definitely give this a try.

Comment: Eric ...I actually got this to work by exchanging the id for a class but i will run your solution and let you know.  Thanks again